# Align Header Menu in the center: Wordpress (Avada Theme) Custom CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

On my website (www.eibenhof.at) I'd like to have the top header menu in the center, at the moment it is on the right. (I will also remove the logo, so that only the text is in the center). However there is no selection from the Avada theme to put it in the center.

First, I was trying to look in the Avada forum for a specific Custom CSS code that I could use and I found this:

```
.fusion-main-menu {float:none !important;}
.fusion-main-menu > ul{float:none !important; text-align:center !important;}
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li,.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a{float:none !important; display:inline-block !important;}
.fusion-main-menu > ul ul{text-align:left !important;}
```

However, this code did not work for me. It puts everything in the center, but it messes everything up! Then I tried to use only "display:inline" instead of "display:inline-block" and it looked alright however I couldn't click on the submenu items anymore.

Help? I'd be so grateful!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Avada theme already has a setting where you can move the nav into the center..

Comment: no it doesn't unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Add css this class

```
.fusion-header{text-align:center;}
.fusion-main-menu{
float:right;/*remove this property*/
/* or */
float:inherit;
display:inline-block;
}

.fusion-is-sticky .fusion-sticky-menu-1 .fusion-sticky-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Great! thanks. the first one : 

.fusion-header{text-align:center;}
.fusion-main-menu{
float:right;
}

.fusion-is-sticky .fusion-sticky-menu-1 .fusion-sticky-menu {
    display: inline-block;
} did not work! 

But the second version (.fusion-header{text-align:center;}
.fusion-main-menu{
float:inherit;
display:inline-block;
}

.fusion-is-sticky .fusion-sticky-menu-1 .fusion-sticky-menu {
    display: inline-block;
} did! 

Just one more thing: I'd love to still have the text in the submenu aligned to the left, not in the center - how would that be possible?

Comment: add this css  .sub-menu li a {    text-align: left;}

Comment: ok thanks, that worked. Just one more thing: As soon as i Apply the code - the submenu is not perfectly aligned to the main menu anymore, it is a bit inside the main menu instead of perfectly connecting to it. Why is that?